# Imposible declarar ToolbarsItems en page.xaml

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Compañeros intento usar los ToolbarItems en una pagina.xaml en Xamarin, pero me está marcando error de sintaxis
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy en un proyecto PCL,instalé el packete nuget SQLite.Net-PCL 3.1.1,SQLiteNetExtensions 1.3.0 y Xamarin.Forms ultima versión

Answer (score 0):

veo que estas intentando declararlo dentro del `<ContentPage.Content>`, quitalo de ahi y colocalo en

```
<ContentPage>
    <ContentPage.ToolBarItems>
       <ToolBarItem IconImageSource=""/>
     </ContentPage.ToolBarItems>
   <ContentPage.Content>
       <Stacklayout>
      </Stacklayout>
   </ContentPage.Content>
 </ContentPage>
```

Saludos, marcalo la respuesta como correcta si te sirvio.

Comment: ok, gracias amigo, no sé porque en un tutorial si les funcionó declarandolo ahí

Comment: Quizas viste que lo pusieron al fondo, que ese no es el problema pero si es que este dentro del contentPage.Content

Comment: no te olvides de marcar como correcta la pregunta si te soluciono el problema.